# Ember.js: bindAttr only expects a boolean

Tags: view, ember.js, templatebinding

Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uB5tX/1/). I'm trying to add the class-names a and b, but what I get is an empty class. For example, if I change it to

```
{{ bindAttr class="str:a:b}}
```

I get **a**
Furthermore, is it possible to add some other (default) classnames too ?

```
{{ bindAttr class"str className1 className2"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! Your syntax is just a bit wrong. The syntax for adding a default class is only `:className`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/7/) is a simple jsfiddle to show you.

What your first line of code actually states is that if str is true, then assign class 'a' to the element, otherwise class 'b' (which is why you only get 'a' as the assigned class). An example of conditional classes is in an updated version of your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/uB5tX/2/).

Comment: Consider [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HG64E/14/) jsfiddle. Here the classes **a** and **b** are added, but in my original example they're not. Any suggestion what is wrong ?

Comment: Ah well if you're binding through the view/controller then it wants the classes as an array - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HG64E/15/).